# How does grub find the device in which grub.cfg resides?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub

As I understand it, the uefi bios loads grub.efi from the efi partition. This now loads a bunch of grub modules and the configuration file from the /boot directory.

But how does grub find the correct device in which the boot partition resides? In grub legacy, you'd usually install grub to a specific partition, using

```
# grub-install --root-directory=/dev/sda
```

So it's quite clear where it will look for the boot directory. How does grub-efi figure out the correct device?